# CGContext addQuadCurve add an arrow

Tags: xcode, draw, cgcontext

if I draw a quadCurve using

ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
ctx.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: x + dist, y: y), control: CGPoint(x: x + dist/2, y: y - arcY))

I want to draw an arrow at the top of the the curve to indicate direction.  I can obtain the X of the  arrow and I know at that point it will be a horizontal arrow.  Can I determine the Y value of the curve at that X value?

I am not stuck on using addQuadCurve, in fact addCurve gives a nicer curve. Just want a solution where I can get the Y value of the arrow and draw it.

The dots represent the control point, I want to draw the arrow at the top of the curves. I know the X value but what is the Y value?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of curves are just math, and you can calculate that math directly. Since you said you'd prefer `addCurve`, the math for that is a cubic Bézier. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) has a pretty nice article on the Bézier function, and we can grab the formula from there:

[image: Bezier formula]

The important thing to remember about this formula is that the dimensions (coordinates) are all independent. If you want to compute the Y coordinate of the curve, you only need the Y coordinates for the control points. It's also useful to understand that the function is generally computed from t=0 to t=1 where t=0 is the starting point and t=1 is the ending point, and t=0.5 is the midpoint. (Note that t=0.25 is *not* the quarter-point. Moving along this curve at a constant rate is a bit more complicated.)

So what does that look like in programmer speak?

```
func bezier(t: CGFloat, P0: CGFloat, P1: CGFloat, P2: CGFloat, P3: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return pow(1 - t, 3) * P0
        + 3 * pow(1 - t, 2) * t * P1
        + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t, 2) * P2
        + pow(t, 3) * P3;
}
```

(This is not an efficient implementation. It's meant to match the formal definition as closely as possible to make it easier to understand. If you want some tips on making it faster, see [Introduction to Fast Bezier](http://robnapier.net/fast-bezier-intro).)

So say your first point (P0) was at (0,0), your first control point (P1) was at (5,5), your second control point (P2) was at (10, 5), and your final point (P3) was at (10,0), then the point half-way along the curve (t=0.5) is:

```
bezier(t: 0.5, P0: 0, P1: 5, P2: 5, P3: 0) // 3.75
```

In many cases you'd also like the derivative (tangent slope) of the curve, and that's also available on the same page:

[image: First-derivative of the Bézier function]

You can use that to work out how to draw a line tangent to the curve, that's not necessary in your case since you know it's horizontal, but often it's useful.

If you decide to use a quad curve, that equation is also available on the same page and would be used the same way.

There's nothing magical about Bézier curves. They're just the plot of an interesting and useful function that can be generally understood with some first-year Algebra. If you study the "Constructing Bézier curves" section, and stare at the animations for a while, much of the mystery may disappear (hopefully replaced with a sense of awe at their beauty).

Comment: @Rod What a great answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I changed my code to use your method of finding the Y value at the half way mark.  Also thinking of using your derivative formula to draw arrow heads (at the correct angle) at the end point of the arc.

Answer (score 0):

Well no-one seemed interested in this question and as the OP I must say I don't blame them.  However, even though noone will probably ever read this I feel obliged to post a solution which worked for me for this specific application.

What I did was to use 'addEllipse' to draw an ellipse and then just drew the arrow head in the top of the ellipse (i.e. y = height_of_ellipse/2 and x = width_of_ellipse/2).  The i just wiped out the bottom half of the ellipse using 'fill' rectangle.

This is a very specific solution to a very specific problem.

Comment: Suggest that anyone looking at this answer should ignore it and look at @Rod Napier answer,  this method works but is clumsy and ugly when compared to his.